# не изменяется ширина столбцов в документе Word

Tags: python, ms-word, docx

Создаю программно документ но не изменяется ширина какие бы параметры в ширину не ставил.Открываю документ ширина каждого столбца 9 см.
document = docx.Document()

```
        section = document.sections[0]  
        section.left_margin = Inches(0.5)
        section.right_margin = Inches(0.5)
        section.top_margin = Inches(0.5)
        section.bottom_margin = Inches(0.5)

        title = "Товар: " + tovar
        document.add_heading(title, level=0)  
      
        table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)
        table.autofit = False  
        table.allow_autofit = False

        # # (первый столбец для изображения, второй для текста)
        table.columns[0].width = Inches(2)
        table.columns[1].width = Inches(6)
```

Comment: Запиши макрос с изменением ширины столбца. Это не может не сработать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051462/python-docx-how-to-set-cell-width-in-tables